# Variable was not created in the distribution strategy scope with costum Layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, tpu

I'm trying to finetune a BERT-Model on Google-colaboratory with TPUs. But I always get the following error:

> ValueError: Variable (tf.Variable 'bert_layer_module/bert/encoder/layer_10/attention/output/LayerNorm/beta:0' shape=(768,) dtype=float32) was not created in the distribution strategy scope of (tensorflow.python.distribute.tpu_strategy.TPUStrategyV1 object at 0x7f6a1fad3390). 
>   It is most likely due to not all layers or the model or optimizer being created outside the distribution strategy scope. Try to make sure your code looks similar to the following.
>
> with strategy.scope():
>
> > model=_create_model()
> >
> > model.compile(...)

My code is based on [this notebook](https://github.com/strongio/keras-bert/blob/master/keras-bert.ipynb)! I altered it for my specific problem and obviously tried to run it on TPU.

I have a costum Layer BertLayer which is apparently created outside the scope:

```py
class BertLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, n_fine_tune_layers=10, **kwargs):
        self.n_fine_tune_layers = n_fine_tune_layers
        self.trainable = True
        self.output_size = 768
        super(BertLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.bert = hub.Module(
            bert_path,
            trainable=self.trainable,
            name="{}_module".format(self.name)
        )
        trainable_vars = self.bert.variables

        # Remove unused layers
        trainable_vars = [var for var in trainable_vars if not "/cls/" in var.name]

        # Select how many layers to fine tune
        trainable_vars = trainable_vars[-self.n_fine_tune_layers :]

        # Add to trainable weights
        for var in trainable_vars:
            self._trainable_weights.append(var)

        # Add non-trainable weights
        for var in self.bert.variables:
            if var not in self._trainable_weights:
                self._non_trainable_weights.append(var)

        super(BertLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, inputs):
        inputs = [K.cast(x, dtype="int32") for x in inputs]
        input_ids, input_mask, segment_ids = inputs
        bert_inputs = dict(
            input_ids=input_ids, input_mask=input_mask, segment_ids=segment_ids
        )
        result = self.bert(inputs=bert_inputs, signature="tokens", as_dict=True)[
            "pooled_output"
        ] 
        return result

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], self.output_size)
```

The model creation is done here:

```py
def build_model(max_seq_length): 
    output_classes = train_labels[0].shape
    # Build model
    in_id = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), name="input_ids")
    in_mask = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), name="input_masks")
    in_segment = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(max_seq_length,), name="segment_ids")
    bert_inputs = [in_id, in_mask, in_segment]

    # Instantiate the custom Bert Layer defined above
    bert_output = BertLayer(n_fine_tune_layers=10)(bert_inputs)

    # Build the rest of the classifier 
    dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(bert_output)
    pred = tf.keras.layers.Dense(train_labels.shape[1], activation='sigmoid')(dense)

    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=bert_inputs, outputs=pred)
    return model
```

the error occures when calling model.compile

```
strategy = tf.distribute.experimental.TPUStrategy(
    tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(TPU_ADDRESS))
with strategy.scope():
  model = build_model(256)

  opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001)
  model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=opt)
```

As I understand it, the BertLayer is indeed created within the scope, but I'm relatively new to keras and tensorflow, so I'm happy for your help. I'm working on tensorflow 1.14

Answer (score 1):

consider to specify the shape of model inputs in the strategy scope, you can try one of the below:
1. call `model.build()` after the model is created.
2. define `input_shape` of the first layer of the model in the `__init__()`.
3. use a real tensor(ones, zeros, ect.) to call `model(tensor)` after the model is created.

anyway, specify the shape of the model inputs. this works for me.
 hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Something that just worked for me was to do the entire model definition (not just the `model = build...()` statement) within the `with tpu_strategy.scope():` block.

I was using the Keras functional API, and I thought I could define the model layers as usual, and then only place the `model = keras.Model(inputs=model_inputs, outputs=model_outputs)` within the `with tpu_strategy.scope():` block. However that didn't work.

In your specific case, that would be placing the `class BertLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):` and all other functions/classes/etc incorporated in the eventual model, within a `with tpu_strategy.scope():` block.